# Why `BehaviorSubject` doesn't emit the last value

Tags: javascript, rxjs

The [documentation on BehaviorSubject](http://reactivex.io/documentation/subject.html) states that it should return the last emitted value regardless of when I subscribe but it doesn't return it for me:

```
const ofObservable = Rx.Observable.of(1, 2, 3);
const subject = new Rx.BehaviorSubject();
ofObservable.subscribe(subject);

subject.subscribe((v) => {
    console.log(v);
}, null, () => {
    console.log('completed');
});
```

The code logs `completed` only.

The `ReplaySubject` works as expected with the above code and log `1, 2, 3, completed`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is somewhere else.

When you use `ofObservable.subscribe(subject)` the source Observable emits also the `complete` notification which marks the `Subject` as stopped and it will never ever emit anything.

So a solution in this use-case could passing only the `next` signals:

```
ofObservable.subscribe(val => subject.next(val));
```

See demo: http://jsbin.com/limurip/3/edit?js,console

Comment: thanks, why does `ReplaySubject` work then? Isn't it affected by `complete` emitted from the source observable?

Comment: and with the approach you described the subject will never complete, right?

Comment: Apparently not, the `ReplaySubject` in fact doesn't subscribe but it replays all the stored values anyway. You can see it here https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/ReplaySubject.ts#L41. I think it makes sense, because `ReplaySubject` should really replay the entire sequence of items while `BehaviorSubject` is supposed to behave like the base `Subject` class but only guarantee that it always emits at least one item.

Comment: And yes, it won't complete if you pass only the `next` signals.

Comment: thanks, but still a bit confusing... ReplaySubject replays everything and completes. I as expecting BehaviorSubject to work similarly. But I understand the mechanics and why they differ. I need to experiment more with them.

Comment: maybe you should also update the docs you referenced with this information

Comment: @Maximus I think I'll post an issue to rxjs repo asking whether it's designed to work this way since it's undocumented.

Comment: `AsyncSubject` is another interesting case in that it waits for the observable stream to complete, but instead of stopping emitting the last value like `BehaviorSubject` it begins emitting it. So the again the article you mentioned doesn't extend to all subject categories

Comment: @Maximus You're right, I should update it with `ReplaySubject` and `AsyncSubject`.