# Why does my BehaviorSubject loose the values when I change pages?

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I already search a previous post corresponding to my problem but I didn't find.

I tried the solution presented [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45054985/why-behaviorsubject-doesnt-emit-the-last-value) but it does not work for me.

Here is my problem. I use user accounts on my website. There are different accounts(customer, admin, manager...). The navbar is adapted to the user account type (one user account = one navbar).
The navbar is loaded from db.

The User Account model includes an array (specific property) to store navigation infos.

For that I use an authentication service presented below :

```js
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})

export class AuthService {

public currentUserSubject$ = new BehaviorSubject<UserAccount>({} as UserAccount);
public currentUser$: Observable<UserAccount>;

constructor( private http: HttpClient) { 
  this.currentUser$ = this.currentUserSubject$.asObservable();
}

public get currentUserValue(): UserAccount {                 
  return this.currentUserSubject$.getValue();
}            

public get currentUserSubjectValue(): UserAccount{
  return this.currentUserSubject$.getValue();
}

getCurrentUserSubject(): BehaviorSubject<UserAccount> {      
  return this.currentUserSubject$;
}

getCurrentUserObs(): Observable<UserAccount> {               
  return this.currentUser$;
}

LogIn(login: string, password : string): Observable<UserAccount>{
  let apiUserAccount: string = environment.apiAddress + 'UserAccount/' + 'Login?' + 'login=' + login + '&' + 'password=' + password;
  return this.http.get<UserAccount>(apiUserAccount);
}

getNavigation(accountTypeId: number) : Observable<Navigation[]> {
  let apiNavigation: string = environment.apiAddress + 'NavigationByUser/' + accountTypeId;
  return this.http.get<Navigation[]>(apiNavigation);
}

logout() {
  const user = {} as UserAccount;        
  this.updateAndEmitCurrentUser(user);   
}

isLogged(): Observable<boolean> {
  return this.currentUserSubject$.pipe(
    map((user: UserAccount) => <boolean>user.isLogged),  
    take(1)
  );
}

updateCurrentUser(user: UserAccount) {
  this.updateAndEmitCurrentUser(user);
}

updateAndEmitCurrentUser(user: UserAccount) {
  localStorage.setItem("currentUser", JSON.stringify(user));      
  this.currentUserSubject$.next(user);  
}
}
```

My Home component contains :
`currentUserSubject$= new BehaviorSubject({} as UserAccount);`
And in the constructor I do this :

```js
constructor(private router: Router,private authService: AuthService) { 
    this.currentUserSubject$ = this.authService.currentUserSubject$;
}
```

If user is not logged I need to load on my home page the default navbar.
Therefore I create an empty user account in ngOnInit to stored into it the navigation informations.

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
    if(this.authService.getCurrentUserSubject().getValue().isLogged === undefined){
        const user = {} as UserAccount;
        this.authService.currentUserSubject$.next(user);
        this.authService.getNavigation(this.userAccountType.Customer).subscribe((navigation: Navigation[]) =>{
          user.navigation = navigation;
          user.isLogged = false;
        });
        this.authService.currentUserSubject$.next(user);
        console.log('Header => ' + JSON.stringify(user, null, 4));
    }
}
```

On the first time the navbar on home page is ok, but if I change page by clicking on login page, the navbar desaper.
The observable currentUserSubject$ property is empty when I try to display his content in the console.
currentUserSubject$ property is also declared on Online page like this : `currentUserSubject$ = new BehaviorSubject({} as UserAccount);`

My submit method on login page is :

```js
onSubmit() {
    this.authService.LogIn(this.f.login.value, this.f.password.value).subscribe((user: UserAccount) => {
    if(user){
        let userAccountTypeId = user.userAccountTypeId.valueOf();
        let truckId = user.truckId?.valueOf();
        this.authService.getNavigation(userAccountTypeId).subscribe((navigation: Navigation[]) =>{
        user.navigation = navigation;
        user.isLogged = true;
        this.authService.currentUserSubject$.next(user);
        this.router.navigate([`/useraccount/${truckId}`]);
        });
    }
  }); 
}
```

In the Header component I also declare the BehaviorSubject property like this: `currentUserSubject$ = new BehaviorSubject({} as UserAccount);`

Is there something I’m doing wrong?
Sorry if I was a little long.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You do not seem to be subscribing to your currentUser$ BehaviorSubject anywhere in the code shown, so nothing will happen when the subject emits its next value.

Comment: Thanks Mikkel. I think I don't use it but I added the subscription on in header, home and login. Nothing changes. Datas are stored in currentUserSubject$

Comment: I confirm that currentUser$ is never used. I removed it. But It still doesn't work.

Comment: Is your `LogIn` function correct? You return the result of the http call directly rather than updating the BehaviorSubject

Comment: I doe it when I subscribe to LogIn function No? Is this not the right way?